# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLServletRegistrationBean' parameter 0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graphql, dependencies

having this file structure:

```
.
├── demo.iml
├── HELP.md
├── mvnw
├── mvnw.cmd
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── com
    │   │       └── example
    │   │           └── demo
    │   │               ├── DemoApplication.java
    │   │               ├── domain
    │   │               │   └── bank
    │   │               │       ├── BankAccount.java
    │   │               │       └── Currency.java
    │   │               └── resolver
    │   │                   └── BankAccountResolver.java
    │   └── resources
    │       ├── application.properties
    │       └── graphql
    │           ├── bank
    │           │   ├── bankAccount.graphql
    │           │   └── currency.graphql
    │           └── query.graphql
    └── test
        └── java
            └── com
                └── example
                    └── demo
                        └── DemoApplicationTests.java
```

and having this `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <graphql-version>11.1.0</graphql-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart
            </groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${graphql-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>playground-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${graphql-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If I try to run this app (`mvn spring-boot:run`), I got:

```
Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLServletRegistrationBean' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/spring/web/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLServletRegistrationBean' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLHttpServlet' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/spring/web/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLHttpServlet' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLServletConfiguration' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/spring/web/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLServletConfiguration' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'invocationInputFactory' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/spring/web/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'invocationInputFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchemaProvider' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/spring/web/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchemaProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchema' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/tools/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchema' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParser' defined in class path resource [graphql/kickstart/tools/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [graphql.kickstart.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No graphql schema files found on classpath with location pattern '**/*.graphqls'.  Please add a graphql schema to the classpath or add a SchemaParser bean to your application context.
```

But why? I have all needed dependency for graphql, but still there is some unsatisfied dependency. What is it?

Answer (score 2):

These errors are very confusing, but your application can't run because it don't find any schemas.

```
No graphql schema files found on classpath with location pattern '**/*.graphqls'.  Please add a graphql schema to the classpath or add a SchemaParser bean to your application context.
```

The graphql schemas in a java environment mostly ends with `s` or you can specify your own schema parser ([Docu](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot#graphql-java-tools)).

**Hint:**
The most gql exceptions have a large stackstrace and all starts with a ServletException but is caused by something else.